# Graphics3D object from the Plot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How can I make a "normal size" (*not stretched*) `Graphics3D` object from the following `Plot3D`?

```
im = Plot3D[-HurwitzZeta[-n, 1 + x] + Zeta[-n], {x, -4, 8},
{n, -8,8}, PlotPoints -> 60, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
ColorFunction -> Hue, ImageSize -> 800, ClippingStyle -> Blue, 
Lighting -> "Neutral", Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, 
Axes -> False, MaxRecursion -> 5, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

```
Graphics3D[{im[[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are after - `im` **is** a `Graphics3D` object.  `im[[1]]` is a `GraphicsComplex`, and `im[[2]]` is a list of options.  To avoid the stretching you are seeing, you could use `Graphics3D[First@im, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]`, but really you are better off just deleting what options you don't want from `im` directly.

Comment: @JasonB. I want to export it  to the STL format,  I tried  `Export["stl.stl", 
 Graphics3D[First@im, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}], "STL"]` but the result is also stretched...

Comment: Try plotting `(-HurwitzZeta[-n, 1 + x] + Zeta[-n])/1200` or use whatever scale works for you instead of `1200`.  It sounds like the STL exporter is using the actual coordinates and ignoring `BoxRatios`.  The `BoxRatios` are used by the Front End to rescale the image.  They don't actually affect the internal geometry of the graphics.

Comment: Now that is a decent question, most likely you need to rescale the coordinates

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty method, which rescales the $x$, $y$, and $z$ directions of the plot to go from $0$ to $1$,

```
im2 = ReplacePart[im, {1, 1} -> Thread[Rescale /@ Thread[im[[1, 1]]]]];

Import@Export["test.stl", im2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Start with the plot:

```
p1 = Plot3D[Zeta[-n] - HurwitzZeta[-n, x + 1], {x, -4, 8}, {n, -8, 8},
            Axes -> None, Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ClippingStyle -> Blue,
            ColorFunction -> Hue, Exclusions -> {{Sin[π x] == 0, x <= -1}},
            Lighting -> "Neutral", MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotPoints -> 30];
```

(Note the use of `Exclusions` to properly handle the singularities in `HurwitzZeta[]`.)

For purposes of rescaling, let's look at the `PlotRange`:

```
PlotRange[p1]
   {{-4., 8.}, {-8., 8.}, {-524.866, 876.366}}
```

From this, I make a rough estimate of what to put in `ScalingTransform[]`:

```
Graphics3D[Cases[p1, GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> 
                 GraphicsComplex[ScalingTransform[{1, 1, 1/150}][pts], rest], ∞],
           Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> Automatic,
           Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewPoint -> {-2.4, -1.3, 2.}]
```

[image: rescaled Hurwitz zeta function]